# gin - problem accessing url-encoded path-param containing forward slash

Tags: go, urlencode, go-gin, path-parameter

For a given route with path param (example below)

```
router.GET("/employee/:id", empHandler.GetEmployee)
```

When tried to invoke the url with id path-param(encoded) containing forward slashes

> id = 21/admin/527
>
> url-encoded id = 21%2Fadmin%2F527

```
https://localhost:8000/emplayee/21%2Fadmin%2F527
```

I'm getting 404 when I try to hit this request
It seems that gin is automatically decoding the path param and forming a route with url containing decoded path-param

```
https://localhost:8000/emplayee/21/admin/527
```

I want the exact encoded value for employee id path-param since it is to be used for calling other api which requires it to be url-encoded.

Answer (score 6):

I've resolved this issue by configuring the router with below options

```
router.UseRawPath = true
router.UnescapePathValues = false
```

This resolved the 404 error, also gin context return the same encoded(unescaped) value.
This value can now be used to call the other APIs which requires url-encoded(unescaped) value for employee id

Comment: I wanted to understand why both values are needed.  The gin documentation says : "If UseRawPath is false (by default), the UnescapePathValues effectively is true, as url.Path gonna be used, which is already unescaped."  So that is why both values need to be overridden.

Comment: Is there a similar setting in go-chi?